# How does Android OOM work?

Tags: android

As I know, Android sets a limit on the application memory size, usually 16M. But I feel confused that: 1) Who performs the limit? Who generates the OOM and kills the app? 2) Does the 16M include both Java heap and Native heap or just Java heap?

Originally, I thought it is DalvikVM that performs the limit, and the 16M only includes the Java heap, because I don't think DalvikVM can control the Native heap. But, I saw some articles say it also includes the memory of bitmaps on Native heap. So, my question is how can DalvikVM manage Native heap? How does Android OOM work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Android has a limitation on the application memory size, usually 16M

Nowadays, devices will have a somewhat larger heap, tied to OS level and screen resolution.

> 1) Who performs the limitation? Who generates the OOM and kill the app?

The Dalvik VM.

> 2) Does the 16M include both Java heap and Native heap or just Java heap?

It is just the Java heap... with one notable exception. On Android 1.x/2.x, bitmaps were represented as a small stub (8 bytes or so) in the Dalvik heap, with the rest of the data in native memory. Those bitmaps were still counted against your heap budget, even though most of the memory was technically outside of the heap. Android 3.0 brought all of the bitmap memory into the heap.

Comment: What makes me confused is the bitmap. Thanks for your explanation!

Comment: Another question is if the limitation is only for Java heap, then with JNI app can have much larger memory size than 16M, right?

Comment: @Todd: JNI code can allocate as much RAM as is available on the device. This does not mean that this is a good idea, from the user's perspective, as apps that use an outsized amount of heap hamper multitasking.